# python instagram submit http 403 error

Tags: python, http, authentication, instagram, mechanize

I learned python 2 days. I wanna... Just login Instagram and get token. Only console. So i used mechanize library.. and I need your help.

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

response = br.open(AUTHORIZATION_URL)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['username'] = ''                        # id
br.form['password'] = ''                        # password
br.find_control(type="submit").readonly = False
br.set_all_readonly(False)

br.form.set_value("1", nr=3)
mechanize.urlopen(br.form.click())
#br.submit()
```

"br.submit()" and "mechanize.urlopen(br.form.click())" are occur http error 403.
here is error code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\3my\Desktop\Python\Instagram\InstagramByMechanize.py", line 25, in <module>
    mechanize.urlopen(br.form.click())
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mechanize\_opener.py", line 426, in urlopen
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mechanize\_opener.py", line 204, in open
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 457, in http_response
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mechanize\_opener.py", line 227, in error
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 332, in _call_chain
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 477, in http_error_default
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: FORBIDDEN
[Finished in 2.213s]
```

Please help me. 
And Happy New Year :)